# How to make the network map drive visible in the current user when executed as administrator

Tags: cmd, command, administrator, wmic

the command prompt is opened in Administrator mode and executed the below command:

```
net use Z: \\server-address\path /user:test test
```

the command got execute successfully.
but the network map drive with (Z) is not visible some times in "My Computer" window.

How can I make it visible and accessible through command prompt from Administrator mode?

Comment: You can do it. See the following answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31009925/who-is-the-user-when-running-under-administrator-privilege

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Drives are mapped by token. Admins have two tokens, As Admin and as normal user. They are seperate.

Answer (score -1):

A feild to be added in the registry editor of Hkeylocal machine and then reboot the machine. Then it works

Comment: What field is needed to be added with Registry Editor? How can I solve the same problem if the important info is missing on this answer?